# Applying css to some part of typescript variable through interpolation in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

Let's say I have a variable named `data` in `app.component.ts` which is of type `:string`.

In `app.component.html` I am showing the value of `data` to the UI using string interpolation like `{{data}}`.

Now my question is while displaying the value in a UI, I need to apply some **css** to some specific letters present in a `data` variable.

For example:

**app.component.ts**

```
data : string = "stack overflow"
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>{{data}}</p>
```

How to highlight the background color of the word overflow using **css**?. And I hear that ***Pipes*** can be used to modify the value. But here I am in a need of applying **css**.

And one more constraint is there, initially the value will be displayed to the browser; the word to be highlighted will be coming from `input` box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something among the lines of:

.ts

```
  highlightKeyWord(sentence: string, keyWord: string) {
      sentence = sentence.replace(keyWord, 
          `<span style="background-color: #35a5f8;">${keyWord}</span>`);
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sentence);
  }
```

.html

```
  <p [innerHTML]="highlightKeyWord('hello world', 'world')"></p>
```

Comment: Why ${keyWord} instead of {{keyWord}

Comment: `<span style="background-color: #35a5f8;">${keyWord}</span>`
is a template literal and the same as 
<span style="background-color: #35a5f8;">' + keyWord + '</span>'

I'm pretty sure {{keyWord}} can't work since you normally bind to a variable in your component.ts not to a parameter of a function. Even if it did though, there is no point in doing it since the highlightKeyWord function already does the updating. 

A more 'real' implementation would be to have sentence and keyWord as variables in your component and update your html to be: [innerHTML]="highlightKeyWord()"

Comment: how to maintain capital and small letters as it is

Comment: if highlighting words as case insensitively means, we need to highlight the main word as it as

Comment: The current example should maintain the original text as is. Please provide an example of the issue you're having / expected behavior.

Comment: that I did with grouping regex like "(keyword)" and later adding $1

Comment: but the problem here is when I search for keyword like [world] it says invalid regular expression

Comment: replace method should allow regex - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
By the error you're getting my guess is that the format you're passing in is not quite right

Comment: I resolved my issue!, it is because of '[' is not like special character it seems for a regular expression, regex itself uses it like /[abc]/, so need to handle when '[' comes

Comment: for example, keyword = "john" and data = "john is still in the house". How to put keyword and data in the example above?

Comment: Something like this I assume: <p [innerHTML]="highlightKeyWord('john is still in the house', 'john')"></p>

Answer (score 1):

One solution is use pipe to extract given word into separate `<span>` elements:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'letterByLetter'
})
export class LetterByLetter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value
      .split('')
      .map((letter) => {
        return `<span>${letter}</span>`;
      })
      .join('');
  }
}
```

Then in component there is possibility to use the pipe in this way `<div [innerHTML]="data | letterByLetter"></div>`. Notice i've used innerHtml but you can use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) instead - which should be better)

After that you are able to decide how the `span` element should looks. You can set either the class or style directly.

Good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't the styles applied to the <span> still get scrapped if you don't use the sanitizer?

Comment: Yes you are right, if you want apply the `style` to the element you should use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` method otherwise it will be removed.

Comment: I need to highlight only some letter in the whole string

Comment: I understand, you can pass argument(s) to pipe as a second parameter of transform. And later make your logic inside the pipe. For example inside map:
`return letter === 'a' ? 'letter a styles' : 'other styles'`

Comment: Which one is better using pipe or using just a function?

Comment: It depends what you need, I vote for pipe, keep your code clean and delegate logic outside component.